# How to deal with extended testing times?

Tags: productivity

I often find myself writing programs that operate on fairly large datasets and complex problem formulations, which usually take on the order of 30 minutes to 2 days of running to identify a bug. The psychological effect of these long testing iterations can be very taxing, and I find it very difficult to change focus and move my mind off of one program and on to another for the 30-ish minutes that a test is running. What strategies can I employ to ease my mind between tests, and change focus more quickly, to achieve a higher productivity?

Comment: Can you create smaller, shorter tests to give you enough confidence in your work to continue development through a course of a day and run these longer tests overnight? It may not do much for tests that are longer than 14 hours, unless you can work on projects on alternating days.

Comment: Sometimes it is reasonable to be satisfied with smaller tests, however oftentimes it is the very scaling ability which needs to be tested- for these kinds of tests, it is often far from obvious how to reduce them.

Comment: Which brings me back to my question: if you have smaller, faster tests that prove functionality is correct, why can't you work on a project for a day, while running your faster tests to prove correctness, and run these long tests at night and while working on a second program? Your context switching between programs is reduced if you simply don't run your long-running tests in the day time.

Comment: You're doing ETL aren't you?

Comment: I'm voting to close as there are really 2 questions here as I see it: 1) How to retain focus when switching tasks and 2) How to reduce the test time for large datasets.

Comment: @RubberDuck What would make you think that?

Comment: @RobbieDee *experience*

Comment: @RubberDuck Large datasets doesn't necessarily mean ETL...

Comment: @RobbieDee, I'm not convinced that it's two questions... seems like "which approach to take: shorten tests (and how?) or tough it out (and how?)"... there's just one problem here, which is the long tests.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to keep your daily or compile/build tests as short as possible.  Builds and subsequent unit tests should run as quickly as possible.  A day to run tests isn't reasonable, even builds running for more than 15 minutes indicate too much code/too big a project/too many time consuming tests being run.

However, I would not abandon those long running tests.  Instead I would schedule them to be weekly or monthly as part of larger regression suite of tests.  Kick them off on a Friday or Saturday and examine the results on Monday.  If weekly isn't a good interval, go every few days.

Comment: *" What strategies can I employ to ease my mind between tests, and change focus more quickly, to achieve a higher productivity?"* I don't believe you have answered this question at all but there is certainly mileage in reviewing what to test, how and when.

Comment: @Robbie - I guess my answer would be, automate everything.  While tests are running, I am doing other things, and they run many times throughout the day (during and after every build).  All the tests are automated as part of build and/or post deployment activities.  Result collection is also automated as well as we get emails and have dashboards up on monitors review test results.  The only time I spend on times is maybe fixing a broken on or writing a new one(s). They are part of my day, but are not taxing me mentally.